# How to read Room database from asset every time, but not only on first create time

Tags: android, android-room

Now I could use AssetSQLiteOpenHelperFactory to use pre-populated database from asset, but it only happens on first database create. If I update asset database in the app, it still keep old one. How to use latest asset database every time?

```
    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),TestDatabase.class, "test.db")
        .openHelperFactory(new AssetSQLiteOpenHelperFactory())
        .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
        .build();
```

Comment: did you unistalled the previous build and installed new one?

Comment: Hi Karan, thanks for your response. Yes, if I clean app storage data and reinstall the new apk , the database will change to new one. But I like it upates to new database without clean storage data, but only install apk.

Comment: Assets resources are compiled when the apk is build and change only once you install new version.

Comment: After install new version apk, I need to clean app data, or it will keep old version asset database.